# Are there no quick actions when editing razor (cshtml) files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm running a clean install of VS Enterprise 15.5 and have just disabled R# to see what VS is actually capable of lately (and I was tired of it being so slow).

We do lots of work with ASPNet Core cshtml files. I noticed there are no quick actions when editing the razor file. For example:

[image]

The editor can see that a `@using` tag is unnecessary, but there is no quick action (lightbulb) to suggest that it be removed.

Same with a class that is referenced below (`Notification`), there is no quick action to suggest that a `@using` tag be added.

In normal .cs files these actions work nicely, and I am a bit surprised not to see this in razor files. Is something not setup correctly?

Resharper had these suggestions and I figured that VS would as well, but perhaps I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A new Razor editor in Visual Studio with support for quick actions (Ctrl+.) is under development. The image below shows you how to enable the preview for this feature:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/wp-content/uploads/sites/16/2020/07/enable-experimental-razor.png

You can read more here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/new-experimental-razor-editor-for-visual-studio/

Answer (score 0):

> Are there no quick actions when editing razor (cshtml) files?

Nothing build in for VS-2015 or VS-2017.  Although if you just add a web.config and namespaces you don't need any using statements in razor files.